# SSIS - Export Master-Detail data to a single flat file that contains both master and detail row

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I have DB with a master table with its detail table, let's say

```
Master (ID, MField1)
Det    (ID, IDMaster, DetField1)
```

and I need to export a flat file with fixed column size, with both master rows and detail rows, here's below the records' structure:

Master Record:

```
Position    Desc        Length    Default
 1           RecordType  1         'M'
 2           ID          10
 3           MField1     10
```

Detail Record:

```
Position    Desc        Length    Default
 1           RecordType  1         'D'
 2           ID          10
 3           MasterID    10
 4           MField1     10
```

**For example**, if I had 2 row in Master `(1,'MFieldVal1'),(2,'MFieldVal2')` and 3 rows in Det `(1,1,'DFieldVal1'),(2,1,'DFieldVal2'),(3,2,'DFieldVal3')`

I'd export a file like this:

```
M         1MFieldVal1
D         1         1DFieldVal1
D         2         1DFieldVal2
M         2MFieldVal2
D         3         2DFieldVal3
```

So far I built a view which joins Master and Det, and I used it as the source of my dataflow, but I don't know how to create the header row before its details in the exported file.

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Simply use an `order by ID, RecordType` to ensure the rows appear in the correct order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an `OLEDB Source` with a similar `SqlCommand` to generate a column of type `NVARCHAR` that contains the whole row that you need to export to a flat file.

*Note: Flat File must contains only one column in the `flat file connection manager` of type `DT_WSTR` and length equal to `4000` or higher if needed and map the column generated from the sqlCommand to it*

```
SELECT  CAST(DataRow as NVARCHAR(4000))  as DataRow FROM (

SELECT ID ,'M' as RowType ,  
       'M   ' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR(255)) + '    ' + MField1  AS DataRow 
FROM Master

UNION ALL

SELECT IDMASTER ,'D' as RowType,  
       'D   ' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR(255)) + '    ' + CAST(IDMASTER as VARCHAR(255)) + '  ' + DetField1  AS DataRow  
FROM Det
        ) AS TBL
ORDER BY ID ASC, RowType DESC
```

**I made a little experiment in sql server**

```
CREATE TABLE #Master (ID INT, MField1 VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #Det (ID INT, IDMaster INT , DetField1 VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #Master(ID, MField1)
VALUES (1,'MFieldVal1'),(2,'MFieldVal2')

INSERT INTO #Det(ID, IDMASTER,DetField1)
VALUES (1,1,'DFieldVal1'),(2,1,'DFieldVal2'),(3,2,'DFieldVal3')


SELECT  CAST(DataRow as NVARCHAR(4000))  as DataRow FROM (

SELECT ID ,'M' as RowType ,  'M ' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR(255)) + '    ' + MField1  AS DataRow FROM #Master

UNION ALL

SELECT IDMASTER ,'D' as RowType,  'D    ' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR(255)) + '    ' + CAST(IDMASTER as VARCHAR(255)) + '  ' + DetField1  AS DataRow  FROM #Det) AS TBL
ORDER BY ID ASC, RowType DESC
```

**And the result was**

[image]

**Important Notes**

- In the SSIS the destination `Flat File` contains one column of type `DT_WSTR` but in real it contains `Tab` separated columns.
- I used ine column, because it seems that you want to insert multiple structure into one flat file. So it is easier to do it this way

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! This solution rely completely on the SqlCommand, I mean: all the formatting/conversion work needs to be done in the SQL command, I'm not an expert in SSIS, but I expected all the data manipulation work to be done in the SSIS data flow, but since I'm not an expert I may be wrong and the solution provided is a best practice.

Comment: This kind of data manipulation doesn't need the use of data flow task conversion components. And it is easy to achieve.

Comment: Give me a feedback when you try it. If it solved ur issue , it is good to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I think you're right, and also formatting operations are better achieved in SQL. I ended up writing 2 views: one for the header data and one for the details data, every field is formatted as it's needed for the output file. In the dataflow I concatenate all the fields, then I "union all" them and sort them so that they're in the correct order. In the end I would had achieved the same result following exactly the solution you give above. I just thought that SSIS provided more functions to format\manipulate data. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)